# How to get the value of a vue object using selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, vue.js, selenium-webdriver, vuetify.js

Here is my html code:

```
<div data-v-58fe9fbf="" data-v-5de8f7f2="" class="copy-button" id="cta_get_link">
<input data-v-58fe9fbf="" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="copy-button--target v-btn v-btn--block v-btn--flat v-btn--outline v-btn--small theme--light"><!---->
</div>
```

When you view the input box, it has a string of characters which im trying to get with selenium.

`test = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cta_get_link").get_attribute("value")` Returns None

`test = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".copy-button--target").get_attribute("input")` Also returns none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the bellow approach:

```
test = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#cta_get_link input').get_attribute('value')
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the data is in the "value" attribute? By your description of the problem it could be in the "placeholder" attribute.
In that case, this should work:

```
test = driver.find_element_by_id("cta_get_link").get_attribute("placeholder")
```

You can also use the text attribute of the selenium element:

```
test = driver.find_element_by_id("cta_get_link").text
```

- This will give you the visible text on the element.